# Sitecore SXA Search Multiple Dropdown List

Tags: sxa, content-search

Im new in Sitecore, long story short. I wanted to know how to create a multiple dropdown search(filter) in Sitecore SXA (not coding part). *Sorry my English is not good hopefully you guys understand what im trying to say.*

Im trying to do like this.

[image]

But what i've done is:

Scnenario 1:
1. When i choose a "Type" dropdown, it display my correct result in search result field. but when i continue do the "Category" field and choose any one of the option. It's not working. (still remain the first result that i search). 

Scenario 2:
1. When i ignore the first dropdown (Keep Type as Default value-All), and direct search from the Category dropdown(choose anyone of the category option), it still show all the items (like i never do the search function, it still show all the items).

I've tried google search alot of ways to solve my problem but im failed. So i hope you guys can help me on this part. Im really appreciate you help.

Comment: Do you have any code you can share or are you using an out of the box rendering?

Comment: You may wish to start with the SXA documentation here on search facets. https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/sxa-search-facets,-scopes,-and-tokens.html

Comment: @Jen hi Jen, Thanks for your comment, im do not using any codes, all what i done is in the content editor and experience editor. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @MichaelWest hi Micheal, Thanks for your comment too, it is the search facets is the main key? what i've done is the first dropdown is assigned "Type" facets and the second one is assigned "Category" facets. Both dropdown options is shown the correct items but only the "Type" will take effect. Means if i ignore the "Type" dropdown and direct search from the "Category" dropdown, it still show me the default results like never search before.

Comment: I guess that means there is something wrong with the setup of your category dropdown, but without more information we can't tell you what it is.  If you select a category, is a request made to the server?

Comment: @Gatogordo Hi Gatogordo, thanks for your comment! If the Category is second dropdown, the request is not made to the server. (i mean the result is still same, never filter for us.), But if we start from the first dropdown (Type), the search result is show me the correct one, then i continue do the second dropdown filter(Category), it seem like didnt take me to the correct result.

Comment: You might want to take this to Sitecore Slack.. will be hard to answer here without much more info.

Comment: Hello, 
Some steps you can make are:
First verify the "Search results signature" is equal on the three components both Search Result and DropDown Filters.
Verify your Facets, make sure the facet your using is pointing to the correct field and name is correctly written.
Then verify that the facet is selected on you Dropdown Filter datasource.
Publish your entire site, and rebuild index.
Verify if there are any errors on the console when you select a value on the category dropdown.

Comment: @JorgePimenta Thanks Jorge, I follow your way and finally find out what steps missing, because the Search results signature and also the Scope setup... Now im able to filter with multiple dropdown already. Really Appreciate...

Comment: @Gatogordo Thanks Gatogordo, I've solved my problem. Thanks your comment and help too. Appreciate...